# Question regarding Programming in Objective-C 2.0 and Xcode

Tags: iphone

Hey, I'm a new programming enthusiast, just hobbling along on self-instruction. I just installed downloaded Xcode 3 . However, I soon noticed in the first example in the book that my interface and the one in the book are different. The templates are different in my Xcode from the one in the book. Is this because the book was released prior to Xcode 3? I'm not sure if I should return the book and look for a different one, or try to get a previous version of Xcode to use with the book's examples. Suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off looking for a newer book. Older versions of Xcode aren't supported on the current OS version (Snow Leopard).